# Proving a Primary Index on an XML field does not make retrieval faster

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a School Table structured like this:

```
Id Classification XMLData

Where Id is a uniqueidentifier, Classification is a NVARCHAR and XMLData is XML.
```

This table has over 1 million rows. The XML data varies, as in it might look something like:

```
<student><grade></grade><standing></standing><gpa><gpa></student>
```

Another example:

```
<professor><subject></subject><years></years></professor>
```

However, when I try and retrieve the XML data from the table using this query:

```
SELECT XMLData FROM School
```

The query takes approximately 1 minute to fetch all the results.

I tried putting a Primary Index on the XML column using this syntax:

```
CREATE PRIMARY XML INDEX IXML_Value ON School (XMLData);
```

But there doesn't seem to be any time improvements. The retrieval still hovers around 1 minute. Is this normal? Is there a way to get this faster?

For the record, my School table DOES have a clustered Index on the Primary Key (Id).

Comment: You are selecting the whole table (no WHERE clause), it can not be faster then reading all the data. No index will help. Why you need one million rows at a client?

Comment: @Serg I am unfortunately going to have to loop through all the rows to perform some type of calculation Maybe I can do WHERE Classification is 'Student' or WHERE Classification is 'Professor.' If I were to do that, would it make sense to put an Index on that field?

Comment: The XML-index is something one should use only in cases where you *really know what you are doing*. [You might read this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/130969/70663)

Comment: @Cuphead, Try to explain, what you are going to do with *"loop through all the rows to perform some type of calculation"*.

Comment: Btw: *"For the record, my School table DOES have a clustered Index on the Primary Key (Id).."* A **clustered index** on a column typed **uniqueidentifier** is in most cases a really bad idea...

Comment: @Shnugo Basically, if the Classification is a Student, do A. If the Classification is a Professor, do B.

Comment: Index on the field which has very low number of different values most probably will be ignored by the query optimizer, it can decide that reading just data is cheaper then reading index plus reading the data. But it depends.

Comment: @Cuphead, if all rows must be processed by the client, an index will not help (unless it's useful for JOINs, which you don't have). I suggest you focus on client application performance improvement. If you have a CPU bottleneck there, server query performance won't help anyway.

Comment: Are you measuring the amount of time it takes SSMS to render a million rows of XML data in a grid? This isn't a very fair measure unless that is actually how the data will always be used.

Answer (score 0):

> Proving a Primary Index on an XML field does not make retrieval faster

Compare the query plans without the index and with the index and you will see that they are exactly the same so no difference with the query you have.

[image]

If you want to see the index in action you have to use one of the xml [Data Type Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-2017).

```
select XMLData.query('.') from dbo.School;
```

[image]

Down at the bottom right you see the XML index being used. If you look closely you actually see a clustered index seek against a table `xml_index_nodes_4...`. That table holds all the pre shredded nodes and values that your XML documents have and that part of the query plan retrieves all the bits and pieces that makes up your XML and the UDX operator is responsible for putting it all together to a XML document again. I guarantee you that in this case you are better of not using the index. Retrieving the XML blob directly is faster.

> Is there a way to get this faster?

Not really with the requirements you have specified in the question. You should have a look at the possibility to perhaps only retrieve the parts of the XML and only the rows you need need for your client to do its work.